# Define a data validation list using FILTER or similar formula

Tags: excel

In cell A2, I have the following formula:

```
=FILTER(Projetos[Title];Projetos[CategoriaSubcategoria]=A1;"")
```

This returns:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your filter formula in a helper range.

Then use a Named range with the formula:

```
=Sheet1!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet1!$A:$A))
```

And then use that name in the Data Validation.